W: [pulseaudio] sap.c: Unsupported SAP version
I've setup a pulseaudio server on linux using:
pulseaudio --load=module-rtp-recv  --exit-idle-time=-1 -v

I have observed that the pulseaudio is listening fine on UDP port
 $ lsof -i | grep pulse
pulseaudi 19527 u0_a228 8u  IPv4 205655      0t0  UDP 224.0.0.56:37670

Then on a mac using vlc, I've setup a streaming configuration (File->Convert/Stream) with Destination as RTP to 224.0.0.56 port 37670
As soon as I push the "stream" button on VLC, I get a bunch of
W: [pulseaudio] sap.c: Unsupported SAP version.

messages in the pulseaudio server output.
No sound output is heard.
I'd appreciate help to understand both why I get this error message, how to fix it, and is this message the reason why I get no sound ?
